# How we can import/use python 3.4 installed library in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, compatibility

I need to use one python library which is available only in 3.4 but my framework runs on python version 2.7 and i want to use that lib to build 
extension search a lot but found very less info about forward compatibility.
checked lib called **future**  but didn't get much info on docs.python.

anyone has any clue then please share.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, module that are provided for python >3 are absolutely not compatible with python 2. The special future import allows to create a module that is compatible by importing into python 2 some of the behaviors of python 3 that would otherwise be breaking, such as the division.

So most of the time, there is no simple way to import a 3.x module in 2.x, sorry